# Failed to start transcaction when converting backends into modules

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus, gae-module

I am trying to convert **Google Web Application** to **EAR application** (backends into modules).I have created EAR Project and dynamic Web projects for **modules**. I have added old front-end code to the default module & back-ends code to the other modules. Facing problem while adding **data to the datastore** .The old Project which uses front end back-ends working properly,Problem comes when converting backends into module &  `tx.begin() throws Exception` .I have created `package.jdo` for jdo configuration.

***Software configuration:- Eclipse-Juno,Google App Engine SDK:- 1.8.5,JDK:- 1.7.0_65,JDO:-JDO 2.3,DataNucleus Eclipse Plugins :-4.0.0.***

```
PersistenceManager pm  = null;
pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
tx =  pm.currentTransaction(); 
tx.begin();
pm.makePersistent(dataObj);
tx.commit();*
```

Comment: something throws an exception, but sadly you don't state the exception or its stack trace ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is DataNucleaus Enhancement issue. Provide correct jdo files to
>   persistent.xml and Enhance Project. Run the project when all classess
>   enhanced(You will get message on console, how many classess were
>   enhanced.)